# "Access Denied" while doing S3 backup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, backup

I have a problem with S3 backup, using AWS Backup tool.
I want to have S3 bucket backed up but I am receiving Access Denied error all the time.
I am quite sure, that the problem is with the bucket policy, cause when I delete the policy backup works like it should.

This is my current policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1558438618388",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1558438593926",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::<bucket-name-here>",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": [
                        "<some-ip-address>/32",
                        "<some-ip-address>/32",
                        "<some-ip-address>/32",
                        "<some-ip-address>/32"
                    ]
                },
                "ArnNotEquals": {
                    "aws:username": [
                        "arn:aws:iam::<some-user-arn>",
                        "arn:aws:iam::<some-user-arn>",
                        "arn:aws:iam::<some-user-arn>",
                        "arn:aws:iam::<some-user-arn>"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I can't figure it out using AWS docs what should I add here in that policy as a condition, to allow AWS Backup tool doing it's job?
As I said before, When I delete the policy everything works fine.

Comment: Then delete the policy! What is that policy meant to be doing anyway? In general, it is best to avoid `Deny` policies because they can have some unpredictable results. It is better to put the conditions on the `Allow` policy rather than a `Deny` policy.

Comment: is the "Implicit deny" rule in place by default then, when public access to S3 bucket is disabled? "Block all public access" is 'On' anyway.
TBH I did not create that rule, so I can't tell 100% why is that there.

Comment: ALL of AWS is 'deny by default'. Nobody has any permissions unless they are granted by a policy, which can be on an IAM User, IAM Role. Some services in AWS also support resource-based policies, such as a Bucket Policy in S3. A `Deny` policy is only used to override permission that has previously been granted by an `Allow` policy. For example, if an Admin has been granted access to all S3 buckets but there is a sensitive bucket with HR information, then a `Deny` policy could be used to deny them access. However, `Deny` policies can lead to strange behaviours like you are experiencing.